# How to create single post page using Rest API JSON or jQuery for PhoneGap?

Tags: jquery, json, phonegap, wordpress-rest-api

I am to trying create a mobile app using PhoneGap and WordPress Rest API.

here is the code that I am using to get a list of posts.

```
getPosts: function() {      
        var rootURL = 'https://examplesite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: rootURL,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                  $('ul.homepost-list').append('<li class="homepost-list__item">' +
                    '<a href="google.com">'+
                    '<img width="100" height="75" src="'+value.fimg_url+'" alt=""/>'+
                    '<h3>'+value.title.rendered+'</h3>' +
                    '<p>'+value.excerpt.rendered+'</p>'+
                    '</a>'+
                    '</li>');
                    ;
                });
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

This works very well and shows a list of posts.

I am stuck creating the single post link and showing it's content when clicking on the link `'<a href="google.com">'`
I know I can create the link using post ID.
Something like `'<a href="'+id+'">'single-post-link</a>`

but when we click on this link where we should redirect it?
in WordPress we have to send the user to `single.php` .
In PhoneGap/JSON where we have to send it and how to show that single post content?